# Error with IDENT_CURRENT - Invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to update a column in my table which was last inserted. I tried creating this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[msp_AssociateEvent]
(
    @EventId int
)

AS

UPDATE tblFoodMenus set
EventID = @EventId

Where FoodMenuID = IDENT_CURRENT(tblFoodMenus)
```

but it gives me this error:

> Invalid column name tblFoodMenus

Am I using IDENT_CURRENT correctly?

P.S. FoodMenuID is the primary key of tblFoodMenus which is being auto incremented

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? What about 2 users concurrently adding records? What about rollbacks (that will increment IDENT_CURRENT, but not insert a row)? What about when the table is empty or truncated (IDENT_CURRENT will return 1). I can't see this being a good idea in most cases....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table name needs to be in quotes

```
Where FoodMenuID = IDENT_CURRENT('tblFoodMenus')
```

Answer (score 1):

Mark Brackett's comment is right on the money - ident_current is not safe to get you the particular identity generated that you are interested in. Almost always you would want to use [scope_identity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) in the code that does the insert and then pass that around wherever it is needed.